# Trigger to get Prior value of formula field on opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger, formula-field, before-trigger

I have custom formula field return type date **`Last Activity age`** on opportunity. I want to capture **`last to last Activity date`**. So I wrote  trigger but it is not updating Last to last activity date field. Please find below trigger:

```
trigger tupdatelasttolastact on opportunity (before update) {
for (opportunity opps : trigger.new){
    Date newVal = opps.Last_to_Last_Activity_Date__c;
    Date oldVal = trigger.oldMap.get(opps.id).Last_Activity_Due_date__c;
    if (newVal != oldVal){
        opps.Last_to_Last_Activity_Date__c = oldVal;
    }
}
}
```

I checked in debug log but did not find trigger and also disabled all WFR but still no luck Please help me to write a trigger in order to achieve this.

Please find below screen shot

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger to get Prior value of last activity date on opportunity](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129566/trigger-to-get-prior-value-of-last-activity-date-on-opportunity)

Comment: No, that was related to process builder. This question related to trigger could you please check my trigger and let me know where I am doing wrong? @Subhash

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong in the code except that i don't understand why you have taken the list of opportunity called **toUpdate**, For Before Update, There is no need of that list know. Did you try with Debug Logs?

Comment: I tries but not able to read debug log. actually I am new. I would appreciate if you could help me to figure it out. @Subhash

Comment: You have One Date value which is getting from Formula Field and The Prior value of that formula field must come to the another Date Field while updating an opportunity. if that is correct, check my below answer.... If not, Please clarify me....

Comment: Yes you are correct one is last Activity date return type date and second one last to last activity date is date type field. still it is not updating last to last activity date field. it is still blank. @Subhash

Comment: It is updating the same date value @Subhash

Comment: Thnaks it's working fine now. I need one more help @subhash please help me through below question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129243/trigger-to-pull-related-contacts-details-on-task-page-when-new-task-creates?noredirect=1#comment184061_129243

Comment: You might consider using the word `Penultimate` instead of `Last_to_Last`. Much less ambiguous imo.